# Optimal algorithm to follow all Twitter users

Tags: algorithm, twitter

What is an optimal algorithm to follow all Twitter users using the twitter API?  I have been wrapping my mind about this issue and I cannot find any optimal iterative approach to this.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Cause I would like to know if its possible in a certain time frame...college project in complexity theory

Comment: Are you asking for information about the [Twitter Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api)?

Comment: Forgive me if I sound facetious, but why would anyone want to analyse/follow a continuous stream of utter drivel?

Comment: @smirkingman  because intellectual minds like Denver are interested in understanding the underlying algorithmic principle than the mundane gibber jabber :D !

Comment: Once you Follow 2,000 users, you can only Follow the number of Followers you have + 10%

Answer (score 4):

Besides the case of "why would you do such a thing?" and "this will get your IP banned", etc.

This shouldn't be all that different from writing a web crawler. I would start off by finding a few root sources and throwing their follows/followers into a priority queue ordered by number of follows/followers the user has, ignoring follows/followers you've already visited. Then visit the users using the priority queue to find the user with the most new follows/followers, keeping the pq updated as you go along.

Again, this sounds like a terrible idea to implement in practice. Twitter had [190 million users](http://techcrunch.com/2010/06/08/twitter-190-million-users/) in July 2010!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But crawling is not really an option. You see, I am trying to solve this assigment using thr Twitter API since my professor claims he's got an optimal solution, but there's no way to create an "optimal" algorithm for that (in my opinion). So, leaving out real world facts like that one's IP might get blocked, I am just trying to solve this theoretically and define the complexity.

Comment: @Denver This *will* require you to use the API to get the followers/follow list. Without further concrete info of what you need, people are going to struggle to make sense of what you're trying to achieve. Also, putting an API and theoretical together doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a theoretical machine, so time and number of API calls doesn't matter, the solution is simple. Every user has a unique id. A user I am following who created his account last week has an id of 229,863,592, so let's use 250,000,000 as the theoretical end point. You can start with an ID of 1, and use the API to follow each user from 1 to 250000000. Anyone who has deleted their account or has been suspended will return an error when you try to follow them. The Twitter API for following 5,000 users at a time by id is:

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/friendships/create

Comment: To inject a bit of real world API programming, Twitter will stop you from following more people once you get to 2,000. To get around this, you need to manage the following process to get you over this limit, or hire a Twitter API consultant, like me. :)

Comment: Or register 12,500 accounts :)